# What markup languages are used in online forums?

Tags: html, formatting, markup, forum

I'm trying to understand text content presentation in groups and forums. I found that link presentation in StackOverflow style is defined according to the sample below:

```
[cnn site][1]
  [1]: http://www.cnn.com
```

But this does not work for other forums like Reddit etc.

What is the name of this text representation?

What other types of content presentation I can meet in other forums?

Where can I learn about them all?

How do I convert one style to another?

Comment: [BBCode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BBCode) is the classic solution.

Comment: What is relation between terms of Markdown and BBCode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This style is called `Markdown`.

The reason why it does not work on other sites/forums, like reddit, is because it is just not intended by the site owner to be supported.

Using/supporting markdown is not a forced standard or anything else. You can kind of compare it to sites that have HTTPS and those that have HTTP only.

The place where I learn everything about Markdown is this cheatsheet [here](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet).

Just head over there and have a look. Unfortunately this is all I can answer to you, because the other questions are off-topic (and off-SO) and are really broad.

Comment: What are most popular names of others site styles like redit? I found several forums using the same style.

Comment: @vico as stated in my answer there is no standard and many different sites are allowed to use many different styles. No one forces Them to use exact this specific style neither disallows them to interpret the styles different. This is where it gets difficult: a site could use the SO style for links as their image style and vice versa. This way you would misinterpret the information in their style, just because it looks similar to a style you know.